# Rearrange array based on index/value

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have a TCL array , say `arr`. It has the following contents :

```
set arr(apple) "red"
set arr(grape) "green"
set arr(one) 1
set arr(2) "two"
set arr(0) "ZERO"
set arr(banana) "yellow"
set arr(three) 3
```

My aim is to push the element with index 0 to the last while maintaining the same order.
I tried this solution

```
set arrList [array get arr]
foreach {key val} $arrList {
   if {$key==0} then {
       set a [lsearch $arrList $key]
       set arrList [lreplace $arrList $a [incr a]]
       lappend arrList $key $val
   }
}
array set arr $arrList
```

My idea was to append the element and it's value (0 and "ZERO") and then convert it back again to an array. But then I realized that TCL array are implemented as **Hash Table** , so order can't be preserved.

So is there any way to solve this problem ? And if I have made any mistake anywhere , please do the required corrections.
PS : I don't know if this is repeated.

Thanks

Comment: If you care about the order of a key-value structure, consider using [dictionaries](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl23a.html), which are really just long strings of space-separated pairs but done efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

There's a key problem here: arrays have *no* order of keys at all. It's random. (Well, it's deterministic based on the exact history of the hash table behind the array; the algorithm is sufficiently complex that *nobody* remembers it. It's certainly allowed to change when the storage is resized.)

To keep any kind of order of keys, you need to have a list of them. To move the element `0` to the end there:

```
set keylist {apple grape one 2 0 banana three}
set idx [lsearch -exact $keylist "0"]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    # This doesn't assume that you already know the value at $idx
    # You actually do here, but we show the general case
    set keylist [list {*}[lreplace $keylist $idx $idx] [lindex $keylist $idx]]
}
```

Once you've got the order, printing out the array is just:

```
foreach key $keylist {
    puts "set array($key) \"$array($key)\""
}
```

Comment: The printing code is going to get cases with embedded double quotes (and a few other characters) wrong, but it's just for illustrative purposes. There are better ways to do codegen.